# Check Phone number have only digits Sales force validation

Tags: regex, validation, salesforce, phone-number

Irrespective of no.of digits limit or special characters,
Just want to check whether the Phone field have only digits or not.

```
for ex:  (999) 999-9999,
```

it should not check for special chars like (),- 
check only whether the field have numbers or not.
because when i enter phone number `salesforce` automatically formats it (999) 999-9999  this way. so need to `ignore '()' '-'` this chars and check only for numbers.

anyone  please help me with this, how can i write a validation rule using `REGEX` for this.

Thanks,
Neha

Comment: `^\d{10}$`..Assuming 10 digit phone number..It uses java syntax so you need to escape `\d` as `^\\d{10}$`

Answer (score 0):

So - this is a difficult one, because Regex can't really check out of order characters. I think the best thing to do is to check the field with:

`\d` and check if the match is of length 10. This works well for validation since we know we have a phone number field, not a document full of text where we are pulling out phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `(\+?\d+\s?\-?\(?\d+\)?\s?\-?\d+\s?-?\d+)`

This will match +1-(555)-555-5555 or (555)-555-5555 or (555) 555-5555 or 5555555555 etc.. In short it will allow numbers and optional +, (, ), space, -. If you want to allow . then you can add `\.?`